# Excel CountIf with finding number of certain dates

Tags: excel

I have a couple of sheets in workbook, once sheet as a list of client jobs with dates.

On another sheet, I have a summery of jobs and other items. I want to know the tota # of jobs in 2011.

Here's what I have and it's not working:

```
=COUNTIF(Jobs!A2:A50,"*2011")
=COUNTIF(Jobs!A2:A50,"??????2011")
```

Neither of these give results, I wonder if it's because the cells are formated as dates in the Jobs sheet? 10/01/2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
=COUNTIFS(Jobs!A2:A50,">=1/1/2011",Jobs!A2:A50,"<=12/31/2011")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a formula like:

```
=COUNTIFS(Jobs!A2:A50, ">=1/1/2011", Jobs!A2:A50, "<1/1/2012")
```

As an alternative you could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(Jobs!A2:A50)=2011))
```

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution would likely be to create a dummy column "Year" with formula "=year(A[n])" with n as your row number.  It should then prove rather easy to countif on the year column providing 2011 as your condition.

Comment: I'd rather not do that, I rather have it work based off of that single column.